# "Haré lo que pueda". ¿Cómo se dice en inglés?

Tags: traducción, inglés, futuro

"Haré lo que pueda". ¿Cómo se dice en Inglés?

Comment: Hola, Aeigan, te damos la bienvenida. Nótese que tu pregunta no trata sobre el idioma español, sino que es una pregunta en español sobre el idioma inglés. Por tanto, debo votar para que se cierre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las formas básicas para traducir la frase:

- *I will do what I can*
- *I'll do what I can*
- *I will do my best*
- *I'll do my best*